# Why is 'required' validator required for *ngIf to work?

Tags: angular

So I am a beginner in Angular. I have few questions regarding template driven forms.

This is the snippet:

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Email ID</label>
      <input type="text" ngModel name="email" class="form-control" #em="ngModel" required/>
  </div>
  <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="em.touched && !em.valid">
    Email ID is required.
  </div>
```

The above code runs perfectly fine,but If I remove required keyword the *ngIf condition doesn't work how it supposed to.
Can I know what is the significance of 'required' validator with *ngIf?
Also how ngModel with name attribute work behind the scene?

Comment: If you remove required directive, The input does not have any validator to validate the input, so the input field will be always valid.

Comment: How ngModel works: https://angular.io/guide/forms

Comment: when you use the directive `ngModel` your input becomes to a NgControl, see https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel. This make that wkeywords like "required" check the ngControl is has a value. When you use a template variable '#em="ngModel"` you can use in your .html the `em` to access all the properties of the NgModel, e.g. invalid or touched or errors...